# Not getting the same result in Python Tesseract every time I run it

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I'm creating a script for reading information in a game, I need to read the usernames of players, the problem is, since some of them have special characters, I can't get the script to get consistent results.

**Scaled image 2x**

[image: Scaled image 2x]

**Converting to grayscale**

[image: Converting to grayscale]

**Applying threshold**

[image: Applying threshold]

**Eroding the image**

[image: Eroding the image]

I run the script five times and got these results:

```
['W lil Clarke', 'uw SlavBoogie', 'W SHADZ']

['W lil Clarke', 'w SlavBoogie', 'Ww SHAD2Z']

['W lil Clarke', 'uw SlavBoogie', 'Ww SHAD']

['W lil Clarke', 'w SlavBoogie', 'Ww SHAD2Z']

['w lil Clarke', 'uw SlavBoogie', 'wW SHADZ']
```

Here's the code

```py
    # Image post-processing

    kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)

    name_capture_resized = np.array(name_capture)

    name_capture_resized = cv2.resize(name_capture_resized, None, fx=2, fy=2)

    name_capture_gray = cv2.cvtColor(name_capture_resized, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    name_capture_threshold = cv2.threshold(name_capture_gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

    name_capture_erode = cv2.erode(name_capture_threshold, kernel, iterations=1)
    
    names = tess.image_to_string(name_capture_erode, config='-c tessedit_char_blacklist=~ﬂ')
```

What can I do to improve the postprocessing and get the same result every time?

Comment: is the opencv output always the same? if yes, then the issue isn't caused by opencv

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz yes, the opencv output is the same, but I was wondering if there are any tweaks I could make to make a better input for tesseract.
I tried using the english + equation languages but it didn't really work.

Comment: pytesseract many times will give you a result that is a bit different, it will never be 100%

Comment: Please make your case reproducible: Which tesseract version do you use? Which traineddata do you use? Which version of OS, python, OpenCV do you use? How did you run the script five times? Do you get different results if you run OCR with tesseract only (without python, image preprocessing)?